# How to turn colSums results in R to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to get col sum for all the columns and have the result in a data frame with colnames and their sum as two columns. But if I do this, column name seem to become index rather than a col itself.

```
demo=data.frame(a=runif(10),b=runif(10,max=2),c=runif(10,max=3))
as.data.frame(colSums(demo))
```

The undesired result:

```
   colSums(demo)
a      4.083571
b     11.698794
c     14.082574
```

The desired result:

```
colname colSums(demo)
a      4.083571
b     11.698794
c     14.082574
```

How can I add a heading to the column on the left while keep the shape as it is? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> demo = data.frame(a=runif(10),b=runif(10,max=2),c=runif(10,max=3))
> df <- data.frame(colname = names(demo),colSums_demo=colSums(demo))
> print(df, row.names=F)
  colname colSums_demo
        a     4.754546
        b    12.488904
        c    18.152095
```

Answer (score 8):

One possibility is to transpose the result with `t()`

```
data.frame(t(colSums(demo)))
```

> ```
>                     a        b        c
> colSums.demo. 5.782475 10.46739 18.46751
> ```

To change the name of the row in the output, we can use `rownames`, for instance like this:

```
`rownames<-`(data.frame(t(colSums(demo))), "myColsum")
```

> ```
>              a        b        c
> myColsum 5.782475 10.46739 18.46751
> ```

Comment: Best solution in my opinion, since it maintains the `colsums` format

Answer (score 6):

Your desired output can be achieved with `stack()` and `setNames()`:

```
setNames(nm=c('colname','colSums(demo)'),stack(colSums(demo))[2:1]);
##   colname colSums(demo)
## 1       a      4.083571
## 2       b     11.698794
## 3       c     14.082574
```

Comment: +1 Nice wrap of setNames and stack, and I think worth explaining the use of the [2:1] notation as it is not covered in help() of either setNames, or stack, (where I think it is operating), which if absent reverses the presentation, i.e. colSums(demo)  precedes colname.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(demo, sum))
```

The result:

```
         a        b       c
1 6.400121 10.16047 10.6528
```

Comment: `data.frame` much faster than `as.data.frame`

Answer (score 2):

There is now an easy way to do this using the tidyverse function `enframe()`.

```
enframe(colSums(demo))
```

And if you want to use the column names from your example, you can set them as arguments.

```
demo %>% colSums() %>% enframe(name = "colname", value = "colSums(demo)")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` with `melt`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(demo)[, lapply(.SD, sum)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
demo=data.frame(a=runif(10),b=runif(10,max=2),c=runif(10,max=3))
as.data.frame(colSums(demo))

new_table<-as.data.frame(colSums(demo))

new_table %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var ="colname")
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A new tidyverse way!

```
demo %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric)
                           ,sum))
```

and then a `tidyr::pivot_longer` if you want long by colname.